# ./Install -n giving php: no such file or directory

Tags: installation, ubuntu-20.04, freepbx

I am following the steps in this guide to install Asterisk and FreePBX.
https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/how-to-install-freepbx-on-ubuntu-22-04-23-04/

I have complted the installation of Asterisk and now on the FreePBX part.  I am getting stuck on the step that says to do** "./install -n".**  When I press enter i get **"/usr/bin/env: 'php': No such file or directory". ** I am pretty new to linux and I am running the latest ubuntu desktop on a Intel Nuc.

I havent tried much cause I cant find the exact issue.

Comment: Seems like PHP is a dependency, have you installed it?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have no installed php-cli package.

You have to install packages before FreePBX

```
sudo apt install -y util-linux apache2 mariadb-server mariadb-client php php-curl php-cli php-pdo php-mysql php-pear php-gd php-mbstring php-intl php-bcmath curl sox mpg123 lame ffmpeg sqlite3 git unixodbc sudo dirmngr postfix asterisk odbc-mariadb php-ldap nodejs npm pkg-config libicu-dev
```